# How to round time in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, time

I had a problem with the time format of `PostgreSql`.

Example: `00:37:46`

I want to round 14 digits after the `decimal>> 00:38:00` does this work?

Comment: What about this approach `select date_trunc('minute', '00:37:46'::time+interval '30 second')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE_PART('hour', a."FirstIn"::time - b."ShiftIntime"::time) * 60 +
 DATE_PART('minute', a."FirstIn"::time - b."ShiftIntime"::time)
```